# How do i search at a time, in multiple different tables with different column names in sql?

Tags: sql

How do i search at a time, in multiple different tables with different column names in sql?

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user_name LIKE %$term%;
```

Comment: why did you tag javascript, php and html if this is a SQL question?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for and if you are using sql server.

```
CREATE TABLE a (SerialNo varchar(254))
GO

CREATE TABLE b (id int, digit varchar(254))
GO

INSERT INTO a (SerialNo) VALUES ('one')
INSERT INTO a (SerialNo) VALUES ('tone')
INSERT INTO a (SerialNo) VALUES ('phone')
INSERT INTO a (SerialNo) VALUES ('two')
INSERT INTO a (SerialNo) VALUES ('three')

INSERT INTO b (id, digit) VALUES (2, 'ne')
INSERT INTO b (id, digit) VALUES (3, 't')

SELECT a.SerialNo
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.SerialNo LIKE '%' + b.digit
WHERE b.id = 2
```

Below are the result of the above query.

```
one
tone
phone
```

And another query you can write like this.

```
SELECT a.SerialNo, b.digit
FROM someTable a
INNER JOIN someOtherTable b
ON a.someField = b.someField
WHERE a.SerialNo LIKE 'SOMETHING%'
AND b.digit LIKE '%SOMETHING ELSE'
```